# Isometry on invariant subspaces contains invariance?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $L^2(0,\infty)$ and an subspace $A$ that is invariant under dilatation
$$ D_t f(x) = f(tx)$$
$t\geq1$, i.e.
$$ D_t A\subset A$$
Let $V$ be an isometry from $A$ to $A$. Does this isometry preserve the invariance? So does the above imply
$$D_t (VA)\subset VA$$
?

I would really appreciate any tipps on this because acutally I have no idea how I could proof this.

Comment: @elemelons constant functions are not even in your space

Comment: Ah yes, of course constant functions aren't $L^2$. I misinterpreted the question as specifying $A$ is comprised of functions each of which is dilation-invariant, for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion fails. Let $A=L^2(1,\infty).$ Then $A$ is an invariant subspace of $L^2(0,\infty).$ The space $A$ is isometrically isomorphic to $L^2(1,2)$ which is not invariant.

Comment: Yes ut here we have an isometry from the space to the space I believe but since we have an inclusion, here it must not change anything...

Comment: @JulesBesson Yes, we take an isometry from $L^2(1,\infty)$ onto $L^2(1,2)$ which is the natural subspace of $L^2(1,\infty).$ The isometry can be given explicitly.

Comment: Nice and quick! (+1)

Comment: @JulesBesson Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, given an increasing diffeomorphism $\chi:(1,2)\to(1,\infty)$, we have $\int_1^\infty |f(x)|^2\,{\rm d}x$ $=$ $\int_1^2|f(\chi(u))|^2\chi'(u)\,{\rm d}u$, so we can do $f\mapsto \sqrt{\chi'}\cdot f\circ \chi$.

Comment: @elemelons $\chi(u)=(2-u)^{-1}.$